# How to disable low disk space message in Fedora 23

Tags: linux, fedora

What is suggested for Ubuntu doesn't seem to be applicable. I've not found anything that seems to be the core of the issue in /etc/xdg/autostart
I've even moved out baobab.service.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried disabling Gnome's housekeeping?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping active false
```

Comment: thanks Lucas for your reply. The issue has been resolved by a way around. I've removed some notification applet from the panel. Then the message came in a web-like window with an option "do not show this message again", which has been chosen. After that the notification stopped coming. I hope your approach works as well, but can't verify it.

Comment: In Fedora 29 it changed (as usually with gsettings), there is no 'active' key. Now I try to use gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping min-notify-period 10000000 (instead of default 10). That is time in minutes. https://github.com/endlessm/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/master/data/org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping.gschema.xml.in.in